# Disabling TLS 1.0 & 1.1 in Apache 2.4.37 not working

Tags: apache, ssl, centos, tls1.2

Apache 2.4.37 installed on Centos7, there is no letsencryt application installed, there is no Virtual Host in httpd.conf file.

The below are part of the settings on ssl.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES
SSLProxyCipherSuite PROFILE=SYSTEM
</VirtualHost>
```

Also tried the below entry but not working.
SSLProtocol TLSv1.2

nmap shows only tls1.2 enabled, but ssllab and https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test both show tls 1.0 and 1.1 enabled.

```
# nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-10 18:53 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000035s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1

PORT    STATE SERVICE VERSION
443/tcp open  ssl/ssl Apache httpd (SSL-only mode)
|_http-server-header: Apache/2.4.37 (centos) OpenSSL/1.1.1g
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
.
.
.
```

Anyone can help me to find the root cause, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the issue is from AWS Load Balancer. The configuration on the Linux level was correct.